# Complex mysql selection query

Tags: mysql

Data:

1. table **shapes**: shape_id, shape_name
2. table **shape_forms**: shape_form_id, shape_id, shape_form
3. shape_form can be: 0 - **circle**, 1 - **square**, 2 - **triangle** - the number of which for each shape is unlimited

I need 2 queries for selecting

1. all shapes which contains in shape_forms both **circles and triangles** or **only circles** but not squares or only triangles
2. all shapes which contains in shape_forms only triangles

Please, give me some hints for solving this task!
I'm restricted not to use "group by" for shape_forms but if there is no proper solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
select s.shape_id
from shapes s
inner join shape_forms sf on sf.shape_id = s.shape_id
group by s.shape_id
having 
(
   sum(shape_form = 1) = 0
   and sum(shape_form in (0,2)) >= 2
)
or sum(shape_form <> 0) = 0
```

2.

```
select s.shape_id
from shapes s
inner join shape_forms sf on sf.shape_id = s.shape_id
group by s.shape_id
having sum(shape_form <> 2) = 0
```

Comment: thanks! just what i was looking for!
didn't ever think about using complex "having" part :)